# How to solve the drain and sewerage issue along the street curb

Tags: plumbing, drain, landscaping, sewer, backyard

Water always fills on our side of the street curb in front of my house. We have a curb drainage hole on this side, but water still fills up the curb on rainy days. During winter, water would freeze and last couple days. It's dangerous to get my mails.

If I want to fix this issue, who I should talk to? Is it my responsibility to consult and find a solution or should I report to the township?

Many thanks!
[image][image][image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an issue to be resolved by the city or municipality where you live.
Email your local representative as well as the Road or works department or whatever entity maintains the roads.
Be sure to include a picture of the water by your mailbox to show your concern.
Be sure to mention the safety issue when it is icy.

Answer (score 3):

That is almost certainly not a pipe that drains into the sewer, but rather a pipe that drains from a downspout or drainage from the yard to the street.

You can talk to the street maintenance department and escalate it up (mayor, alderman, state representative, etc.), but I don't think you will get very far. That will be a very costly change for the city to fix as I think they would need to re-grade the curb quite some distance. No harm in trying, but I wouldn't expect them to fix it at all, let alone quickly, until the street needs repaired/replaced.

My suggestion is a mailbox that opens from the backside as well as the frontside, also known as a double door, two door, or rear access mailbox.

Example:

[image]

Comment: It will be fine as long as it's the responsibility of the township. My concern is I am responsible for someone fall down due to the ice.

Comment: @YRJ Legal questions are off-topic here and you would really need to check with a lawyer and that answer can change based on where you live. My expectation is that the icing issue is on the street and not your property, so if anyone is liable, it is the city. It would still be a good idea to notify them of the issue so they know it needs remedied.